# Dealing with a sequence of function arguments that may contain lists

Tags: functions

I have a function with multiple input parameters, `Func[x1, x2, x3, ..., xm]`. On occasion a subset of these parameters might be provided as a list `R = {xk, ..., xn}`.

Is there a way of flattening the list `R` so that it can be used as a sequence of parameters in `Func[x1, ..., xk - 1, R, xn + 1, ...,xm]`, without having to explicitly refer to list elements `R[[nn]]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) in conjunction with `Flatten`

```
Func @@ Flatten @ {x1, x2, {x3, x4}, x5}
(* Func[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5] *)
```

You could make this more concrete by defining it as a `DownValue` of `Func`,

```
Func[x_List] := Func @@ Flatten@x
```

So that now, if you give it a list of elements, no matter how convoluted, it will flatten them

```
Func[{x1, {x2, {x3, x4}, x5}}]
(* Func[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, I think :

```
ClearAll[g]
g[a___, b_List, c___] := g[a, Sequence @@ b , c]
(g[x1___ ] /; FreeQ[{x1}, List[___], {1}]) := yourDefinition[x1]
```

It could work without `/; FreeQ[{x1}, List[___], {1}]` , but there may be a problem with the order in which the definitions are applied. It's not fully documented.

```
g[1, {2, 7}, {3, 9}]
g[1, 2, 3]
```

> yourDefinition[1, 2, 7, 3, 9]
>   yourDefinition[1, 2, 3]

Comment: I would have done something like `g[a___, {b___}, c___] := g[a, b, c]` myself.